# Close the Popup window using selenium (java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

How to close the popup modal dialog box using selenium (Java) tool for the below screenshot?
[image: Kindly Refer ans suggest]

Comment: Is this pop up a part of DOM or it's a separate window?

Comment: Just locate (take an XPath for) the Close button and click on it. Can you provide us the HTML code for Close button.

Comment: It is a part of DOM and HTML code for the close button is <button class="action-close" type="button" data-role="action"><span>X</span></button>. I have tried to close the popup using x-path. But it's not working

Comment: Is it Windows Popup or Bootstrap Popup?

Comment: It is Bootstrap Popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things you could try here

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert().dismiss();
```

My other theory is that if you have tried to dismiss it manually through finding an ID for the X in the corner and trying to click it, you may have to wait until the element is clickable.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath);
if (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()) {
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: The issue is solved. It is not an alert. Your second suggestion is the solution for that. Thanks Jack